# How to redirect image path to different path with the same image name using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, path

I have a path to my images path which looks like this `example.com/image/file.png` and some how i did this `example.com/Image/file.png` spacifying the image path with uppercase letter. How do i redirect every image on my page that is pointing to uppercase to lower case path?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/777577/apache-rewrite-all-urls-to-lowercase-if-contains-at-least-one-uppercase - you will find more about this here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect  `/Image/file.png` to `/image/file.png` you can use the following Redirect

```
RedirectMatch ^/Image/(.+\.png)$ /image/$1
```